# Is there a way the to change RadChart legend text color?

Tags: telerik, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am trying to style my app with a dark theme and the legend items are black. Is there a way to change the color of the legend items? There is a property to change the title color but that doesn't effect the other series names.

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt4qW.jpg)

```
<RadPieChart allowAnimation="true" height=100% row="1" col="0" colSpan="12">
               <DonutSeries tkPieSeries
                   selectionMode="DataPoint"
                   expandRadius="0.4"
                   outerRadiusFactor="0.7"
                   innerRadiusFactor="0.4"
                   valueProperty="Amount"
                   legendLabel="Country"
                   [items]="Countries" class="white"></DonutSeries>
               <Palette tkPiePalette >
                       <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#EB5E55" strokeColor="#EB5E55"></PaletteEntry>
                       <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#D81E5B" strokeColor="#D81E5B"></PaletteEntry>
                       <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#FDF0D5" strokeColor="#FDF0D5"></PaletteEntry>
                       <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#C6D8D3" strokeColor="#C6D8D3"></PaletteEntry>
                       <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#00FDDC" strokeColor="#00FDDC"></PaletteEntry>
                       <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#495F41" strokeColor="#495F41"></PaletteEntry>
                   </Palette>
             <Palette tkPiePalette seriesState="Selected">
                   <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#EB5E55" strokeColor="#EB5E55"></PaletteEntry>
                   <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#D81E5B" strokeColor="#D81E5B"></PaletteEntry>
                   <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#FDF0D5" strokeColor="#FDF0D5"></PaletteEntry>
                   <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#C6D8D3" strokeColor="#C6D8D3"></PaletteEntry>
                   <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#00FDDC" strokeColor="#00FDDC"></PaletteEntry>
                   <PaletteEntry tkPiePaletteEntry fillColor="#495F41" strokeColor="#495F41"></PaletteEntry>
            </Palette>
               <RadLegendView tkPieLegend position="Right" title="Country" offsetOrigin="TopRight" width="110" enableSelection="true" titleColor="white"></RadLegendView>
       </RadPieChart>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's supported as of today, there is an open [feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/250) in Github you might want to follow.

As a workaround you may turn off default legend view and render your own list of legends using Labels.

Comment: Is there a way to still have the Legends functionality, while doing this? It would be nice to still be able to trigger the selected animation when a user taps entry on the legend.

Comment: It might be possible, I see `com.telerik.widget.primitives.legend.LegendSelectionListener` in the plugin source which seems to be relevant, you may have to implement the listener, select / deselect legend. But again as it's not open source, it's hard to debug. Raising an issue on Github may give you some directions.